# Lexus ES330 - cooling fans not coming on, there is a disconnected cable but I can't determine where it goes

Tags: cooling-system, fan, lexus

The car is overheating and I've found that the fans do not turn on. After checking fuses/relays I found the plug in the attached picture was not connected.  However, I can't figure out where the male end is.  I've looked through images and slow motion youtube videos trying to get a glance at it with no luck.

Can anyone tell me where to find where the male connector is? A picture would be great.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this connector is relevant?  Sometimes there are unused connectors on wiring harnesses that are for options not chosen.

Comment: I'm not sure, someone asked the same yesterday so I'm afraid I may have been looking for something that doesn't exist :/

Comment: I doubt this has to do with powering the fans. If you look in the second picture where your middle finger is pointing at, that appears to be the power source for  at least one of the fans (if there are multiple). I'm making this assumption based on the apparent gauge of the wires involved as well as the location. The wires in your hand (not attached to anything) would not be able to carry the amperage needed to power the fans.

Comment: What year is the Lexus?

Comment: [Here is the end of the temperature sender.](https://www.rockauto.com/info/182/NTKEF0105_2__ra_p.jpg) This looks suspiciously the same. This is the one for a 2004, which may/may not be your year, but since there was only three model years of the ES330, they are probably all the same. If the temp sensor is not plugged in, it might not be sending the signal to the computer to turn your fans on. Some vehicles have two sensors: one which feeds the computer information and the other which feeds the dash gauges.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it is an '04, I will investigate the temperature sender

Comment: I was able to get 12v to the plug you reference (that my middle finger is pointing at) and the fans do come on